# Why aren't all points on a rolling ball moving?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-kinematics

> If a ball is rolling down a hill as shown, what can be said about the points indicated at that particular point in motion?
>
> [image: ball in motion]
>
> (A) Point A is moving to the left, Point B is at temporarily at rest, Point C is moving to the left
>
> (B) Point A is moving vertically upward, Point B is moving to the left, Point C is moving vertically downward
>
> (C) Point A is moving vertically upward, Point B is at temporarily at rest, Point C is moving vertically downward

The answer is C, but I don't understand why it is. Wouldn't rotational inertia mean that all the points are still moving?

Comment: Point b cannot be moving up or down (it was just moving down and is just starting to move up). If it was moving left or right, it would be sliding against the ground, which is not right (if your car tires slid for example the rubber would be worn down quickly). So it can't be moving left or right or up or down.

Comment: Does Answer C imply that Points A and C have zero horizontal velocity and only vertical velocity?

Comment: The picture doesn't appear to be showing rolling "down a hill", it looks like the ball is rolling on a horizontal surface.   Suggestion: remove "down a hill" from the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What point are you turning about?

That's right, point $B$! So surely this point will not move, just like when I lift my bike and spin the wheel, the center of the wheel doesn't move.

When this is so, it should also be clear that the straight-line distance to $C$ cannot change. So for $C$ to reach the ground, it must must go downwards and slightly right (so little right, that it doesn't count here)

Answer (score 1):

For pure rolling (no slipping) the ball is rotating about point *B* (the contact point). Thus *A* is moving up and a little to the right, and *C* downwards and a little to the left, whilest point *B* is at rest. If *B* was moving up or down it would break the contact, and if it move left or right it would slip.

Why?

The picture below shows the velocity vectors (blue) of points *A* and *C* as the ball rolls

[image: pic]

The perpendicular to *AB* is along *AB'* according to geometry (lines from diametrical points meet pependicularly). Similarly for *BC* and *B'C*

So the answer is neither of the three actually. This drives the point that physics should be taught at the same time as geometry since they are both actually quite interconnected.

Comment: I have to admit I am a little bit lost here, although I accept your answer. I am not trying to be pedantic in any way, but the question, to me, is also badly phrased and physically confusing. It's a solid ball, so if point b is at rest, then point c must be at rest as well, not moving vertically downward. I do see the point of the question, and some leeway in language has to be granted, but my point is that I honestly think that this particular wording may confuse some students and if I was marking the exam I would accept that answer as logically consistent.

Comment: The question says, "Point b is _temporarily_ at rest".  The motion of the ball is a combination of rotation and translation.  Different points on the ball will have different velocities because of the rotation.  The velocity of point B due to the rotation component is exactly opposite the velocity due to the translation component, so _at the instant pictured_, point B is at rest.  This should be intuitively obvious because point B is in contact with the (presumeably) non-moving ground at that instant.

Comment: The question implies that the velocities are relative to the surface on which it's rolling.  I hate it when intro questions imply reference frames. That said, if the reference frame was co-moving with the center of mass of the ball, then all points on the ball are moving at $\omega r$ perpendicular to their position vectors. But relative to the road, point B *must* stop moving down and forward, then start moving up and forward, if it doesn't slip.

Comment: Any body moving in a plane will have one point _with no instantaneous velocity_. This point might be on the body, or away from the body. At that instant all distances from the points on the body to this point remain constant. The body spins about this point.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 kinds of motion here: translational  and rotational.

The net velocity at any point is calculated by the vector sum of these two velocities.

For instance at point **B**, $v-rw=0$ (pure rolling condition).

That's why this point stays at rest.

Answer (score 0):

Additional answer: look up "cycloid" via https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid.  There is a very good description (both pictorially and mathematically) of the path traced out by point B as the ball is rolling along.

Since my last posting, questions have arisen in the comments regarding how point B could be at rest while the ball is rotating.  Please see Figure 9-31, which shows a small spool rolling down a ruler.  Since there are white dots on a black spool, and the exposure time was relatively long, you can clearly see motion, as represented by the amount of blurring of the dots.  Note that the points at the top of the spool are moving at 2v, the center of mass is moving at v, and the bottom of the spool is momentarily at rest with respect to the ruler.
[image]

Image source: "Physics For Scientists And Engineers", Paul A. Tipler and Gene Mosca, 6th Edition, W. H. Freeman and Company, New York, 2008, p. 310.